# Does compromise of one cPanel / WHM account on a server mean the other accounts are at risk?

Tags: web-hosting

I have created multiple cpanel accounts using my server WHM panel.

As of now each domain has separate cpanel in my server.

If one of my cpanel (domain) hacked, does that mean other cpanel are hacked too?

Answer (score 3):

Allow me to start off by saying that setting up a secure WHM & cPanel environment is a very difficult task. There are many source of information on that topic, such as:

- [10 Tips for making your cPanel and WHM servers](https://cpanel.net/10_tips_for_making_your_cpanel_and_whm_servers_more_secure/)
- [WHM Recommended Security Settings Checklists](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/SecureServerChecklists)
- [How To: WHM Server Hardening And Security Basics](http://www.whmsecurity.com/whm/how-to-whm-server-hardening-and-security-basics)

As for your question itself. WHM creates separate cPanel accounts with the aid of the Operating System's access control and permissions; each user has their own directory and they're given access to only what's theirs, so a compromised account shouldn't normally be a problem. **But** if all of your accounts exist on the same dedicated server, it means that an attacker could exploit a [privilege escalation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_escalation) vulnerability to gain access to your `root` account. From there, it's Game Over. All of the other accounts and even your WHM control panel will be compromised.
Another possibility is a vulnerability in the WHM software itself.

The reality of the situation is somewhat different. Yes, there *is* a possibility, but the likelihood is very low. WHM is widely used by hosting retailers and we don't hear a lot about major attacks on it.

**Conclusion:** If you follow the recommended security practices, you've shaved the vast majority of the danger.

Comment: @TildalWave Yes, but I don't think WHM supports that. You _can_ manually setup VMs and install cPanel on each one of them, though. But then you'd lose the central management features WHM provides.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I've removed my comment by now tho, thinking it's an irrelevant additional question. ;) (to anyone wondering what the question was, I was inquiring whether privilege escalation vulnerabilities could be thwarted by using separate VMs per each cPanel client).